# Python How to introduce windows predefined constants into python?

Tags: python, windows, macros

I'm using a windows api to which I have to pass a virtual-key code as it's parameter .

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx

All the virtual-key codes are defined in the "Winuser.h" ,

```
#define VK_LSHIFT         0xA0
#define VK_RSHIFT         0xA1
#define VK_LCONTROL       0xA2
#define VK_RCONTROL       0xA3
#define VK_LMENU          0xA4
#define VK_RMENU          0xA5
```

Is there a simple way, that I can introduce all these windows predefined macros into python with a few commands ,so that I don't need to manually rewrite this .h file in python ?

I can just pass the actual values to use the windows api, but that would make it much more difficult to read or maintain my code .

Comment: If you install PyWin32, it's `win32con.VK_LSHIFT`, etc.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you ,what about ctypes ? Is there a similar module like win32con in ctypes ?

Comment: No, Python isn't distributed with a module of Windows API constants. But the `pypiwin32` package is a pip install away.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you.